# NSTimer Uniqe question

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, nstimer

I'll go straight to the problem.

This ones eating my head since a week.

What i intend to do is set my timer, which is supposed to be fired on main run loop, from a secondary thread. So i do it as follows.

```
if(timerRefresh)
{
    //[timerRefresh invalidate];
    timerRefresh = nil;
}

if (!self.isConnectionAvailable) {
    timerRefresh = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:appDelegate.TimerInterval target:self selector:@selector(startAutoRefresh) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
else if (self.isLivePresent||self.isUpcomingMatchToday) {
    timerRefresh = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:appDelegate.TimerInterval target:self selector:@selector(startAutoRefresh) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
else {
    timerRefresh = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:LongRefresh target:self selector:@selector(startAutoRefresh) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop];
[runLoop addTimer:timerRefresh forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[runLoop run];
```

When this fires, a loader begins loading on the main thread, and the processing work is done on the secondary thread.

I hope this is a correct way.

Now i have a child class within this main class which also has to show a loader while it triggers a filtering process, so to avoid multiple loaders, when the the filtering process triggers, i pause the refreshing on this parent class, by sending it notifications from the child class..like this...

```
-(void)teamNameClicked:(id)sender
{
    BOOL result = YES;
    NSNumber *newNumber = [NSNumber numberWithBool:result];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PauseMatchesLiveMatchTimer" object:newNumber];

    [self performSelector:@selector(sendTeamNameClickToFunction:) withObject:sender];
}
```

and when operation completes i have another notifier as this...

```
-(void)processTeamNameClick:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    selectedIndexDropDown  = button.tag;

    [self parseTeamFile:button.tag];
    self.lblDropDown.text = [dictTeamFilter valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",button.tag]];
    [tblResults performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

    BOOL result = NO;
    NSNumber *newNumber = [NSNumber numberWithBool:result];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PauseMatchesLiveMatchTimer" object:newNumber];
}
```

Notice the YES and NO for results..

Now this is an observer for the notification...

```
-(void)pauseAndResumeTimer:(NSNotification *)notification;
{
    NSNumber *newNumber = [notification object];
    BOOL result = [newNumber boolValue];

    if (result) {
        if(timerRefresh)
        {
            if ([timerRefresh isValid])
                [timerRefresh invalidate];
            timerRefresh = nil;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        if(timerRefresh)
        {
            if ([timerRefresh isValid])
                [timerRefresh invalidate];
            timerRefresh = nil;
        }

        if (!self.isConnectionAvailable) {
            timerRefresh = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:appDelegate.TimerInterval target:self selector:@selector(startAutoRefresh) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        }
        else if (self.isLivePresent||self.isUpcomingMatchToday) {
            timerRefresh = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:appDelegate.TimerInterval target:self selector:@selector(startAutoRefresh) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        }
        else {
            timerRefresh = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:LongRefresh target:self selector:@selector(startAutoRefresh) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        }

        NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop];
        [runLoop addTimer:timerRefresh forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [runLoop run];
    }
}
```

When the filtering process is on, i stop the parent timer. And when off i start it again.

Ok...So now the problem... When i do normal navigation on my pages, it works absolutely fine..like switching tabs, traversing between pages etc.

But if i use the filter process, somehow, it triggers my timer on the main page, and even when the view has disappeared, seems to kick off my timer event. I want to avoid that, but i just dont know how..

If anyone can genuinely help me, please do.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some funny stuff going on in your code:

- First and formemost, I am at least least 90% positively sure that you don't want to call `[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] run]` in any of your program's methods — do those methods even exit, or do you keep aggregating thread upon thread?
- Secondly, your timer invalidations are all a bit strange:

  1. There is no use in `if (timerRefresh) if ([timerRefresh isValid]) [timerRefresh invalidate];`; since in Objective C, messaging `nil` is perfectly fine. The result of such a message is always `0x0`, so the first `if` is unnecessary and the second one evaluates to `NO` in that case, anyway.
  2. Invalidating a timer means removing it from the runloop it was scheduled on. Hence, the second `if` is unnecessary, too — leaving you with just `[timerRefresh invalidate];`.
  3. For `-[NSTimer invalidate]` to have an effect, it **needs** to be called on the thread the timer is scheduled on. From what I understood, this is not the case in all your methods. So you should use `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` with the appropriate arguments instead.
- There is no difference between `[self performSelector:@selector(sendTeamNameClickToFunction:) withObject:sender]` and simply `[self sendTeamNameClickToFunction:sender]`. Except that the latter is much easier to read ;-)
- The `if` clauses in `pauseAndResumeTimer:` don't make an awful lot of sense, i.e. there's a lot of code duplication.

Here is said method in a tidied-up fashion and with the invalidation happening on the main thread:

```
-(void)pauseAndResumeTimer:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [timerRefresh performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(invalidate) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    timerRefresh = nil;

    NSNumber *result = [notification object];
    if ([result boolValue]) return;

    if ( !self.isConnectionAvailable || self.isLivePresent || self.isUpcomingMatchToday ) {
        timerRefresh = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:appDelegate.TimerInterval target:self selector:@selector(startAutoRefresh) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    } else {
        timerRefresh = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:LongRefresh target:self selector:@selector(startAutoRefresh) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }

    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timerRefresh forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight dany..But the thing is i haven't exposed you the complete code here for well organizational purposes. Pause and Resume timer notification method was my only way to avoid too many loaders. See there are two classes here. Class A and B. A is the parent class and B is its child. A does the Main Fetch and parse operation from the Server, and passes it to B to do the display operations. And B has got its own minor fetching and parsing operation when i do a FILTER process.

Comment: Now when i do this parsing and fetching operation i have to show a loader. And this process has to repeat after a certain interval of time which user selects. And again there can be no connection issues and so have to check that too. Now as A does its parsing and loading regularly eg 30 secs, if during that time user kicks a FILTER opeartion on B that would show its own loader. And if that happens when A's refresh is due, it shows two consecutive loaders within short span of time and confuses the user. So to avoid that from happening i had devised this notification scheme.

Comment: But that seems to have messed up my timer logic. The same timer process code applies when i complete one refresh cycle. I had done it that way instead of normal scheduling of timer cos, this is a international app, and not everywhere do we get fast connections, so on Edge it may take a while for the data to load, and the refresh period might be too small as it is set by the user. And if a loading process is ON on a background thread,its not complete, and the timer on the main thread causes another process to start cos time interval has arrived, it causes a crash in my app, cos of too much data

Comment: Hope now u have a clearer vision of my problem, and if you can please help me frame my timer code for the same.

Comment: Oh and ya.. just to be clear, for your third bullet, i know there is no difference, its just that for my loader function to kick in, other wise i am not able to see the loader. Cos that too is on main thread :)

Comment: @swapz Here is how I understand your setup: `a` (an instance of class `A`) has (among others) two members — one timer and `b`, an instance of class `B`. `a` has registered itself as an observer of `b`'s `PauseMatchesLiveMatchTimer`-notification with the `pauseAndResumeTimer:`-method. This notification is posted on two occasions: 1. When `b` starts a certain task on behalf of `a` and 2. when `b` has finished said task. On occasion 1 `a` should cancel its timer, whereas on occasion 2 the timer should be re-initiated. The question at hand is: Which threads are these notifications posted on?

Comment: Good gotcha...I spawn a background thread on 'a' to instantiate an instance of 'b' which then does the displaying of 'a''s data. So i guess by that except for UI stuff, everything on 'b' is processed on a background thread, and hence the notification too i guess is being sent from the same background thread to the 'pauseAndResumeTimer:' method on 'a'

Comment: So will that cause any problem?

Comment: Don't guess: Put a breakpoint into `pauseAndResumeTimer:` and look from which thread it's called. Or, even more efficient to find the crucial invocation, add `NSAssert1([NSThread isMainThread], @"Notification posted on thread %@.", [NSThread currentThread]);` as the first line to that method. An NSTimer needs to be invalidated from the thread where it's scheduled. In your case, that's the main thread.

Comment: [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timerRefresh forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
} What will this line do then?? wont it add the timer to run on the main thread???

Comment: I say this cos when i instantiate 'a' i have done that on the main thread.

Comment: Your problem isn't that the timer runs on the main thread. Your problem is that **you don't know** on which thread you are trying to invalidate it. You need to make sure, that you invalidate it on the main thread as well.

Comment: Does that Runloop line add the timer on the main thread? Cos as i WAS on the background thread i needed a mechanism to stop the timer on the MAIN thread, that is why this whole story in the first place. So please advise.. Will that line if executed from the background thread attach the timer again to the main thread. I will invalidate the timer using performSelectorOnMainThread as u said... But will it get added again if i execute that runloop statement?

Comment: At this point, I'd suggest you give _[Object Messaging](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW5)_ from _[The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163)_ another read. _[Timer Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Timers.html)_ might be helpful, too.